# Having trouble adding a mobile Sign-in redirect URI to OIN’s App Integration form

Tags: single-sign-on, openid-connect, okta, okta-api, okta-signin-widget

After successfully creating an OIDC app on https://developer.okta.com/ and adding both mobile and web redirect URIs and working good in both mobile and web application, I encountered an issue when attempting to submit the form for the OIN in https://oinmanager.okta.com/. An error message was displayed, stating that ‘com.okta.example:/callback’ isn’t a valid URL. For example: https://www.okta.com

Is there a way to configure an application within the OpenID Connect Identity Network (OIN) using OIDC integration, allowing for support of both web and native applications using a unified application configuration?